# Which Zookeeper ensemble I need to start first?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I created 3 zookeeper instances and configured like below in all 3 and respective id in myid file:

```
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2881:3881
server.3=localhost:2882:3882
```

Now, which instance I should start first ?I am getting below when I start server.1 :

```
 WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=1]-1:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address localhost/127.0.0.1:3881
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateConnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:383)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-10-06 00:01:58,734 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=1]-2:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address localhost/127.0.0.1:3882
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateConnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:383)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to run 3 servers on one machine?

Comment: Just for verification purpose I am running in same machine.But I face the same issue when I run 3 different machine too.

Comment: Does it keep trying to connect? That warning will be printed until the other servers are running.